How can I show that you can't define an inner product from an isomorphism to the dual space?
An isomorphism $T$ from a finite-dimensional vector space $V$ to its dual $V^*$ induces a bilinear form on $V$ via $(v,w) \mapsto T(v)(w)$.  If this bilinear form happens to be symmetric and positive definite, it will give an inner product.  Usually this will fail to be the case, but one might wonder if there is some more elaborate construction in terms of $T$ that would define an inner product.  I can't see any way to do it using first-order quantification over $V$ or even higher-order quantification, and I suspect it is impossible.  But how can I prove this?  (More precisely, for the higher-order case, how can I prove that there are models of ZFC where definability fails, since there will trivially be a definable inner product on $V$ without even needing to use $T$ if there is a definable wellorder of $V$.)

I don't think "construction in terms of $T$" is sufficiently well-defined for your question to have any definite answer as it stands.

So what you're asking is whether there is a formula, possibly infinitary, in the two-sorted language of a vector space, its dual, and an isomorphism between them, such that this formula always yields an inner product on the vector space sort (in a standard model). Is that right?

I think this can probably be shown by finding such a thing with no automorphism invariant inner product. I suspect this is probably true in the three dimensional space.

And I think it can be phrased in terms of commuting with a transpose-closed algebra of matrices generated by a single symmetric matrix. I don't have the time to figure it out now though.

Thanks, @tomasz, this gives me some food for thought!

$\newcommand{\bR}{\mathbf R}$Here's an answer to a variant formalisation of your question. Mind, I'm only talking about internal definability, not external (the external version you allude to near the end would follow if you could show that consistently, there is a $2$-dimensional real vector space and a quadratic form such that all definable subsets are definable in the vector space itself; I suspect this sort of thing might be known to some set theorists, but it is not really my expertise).
Consider $V=\bR^2$ with the Lorentzian form $x^2-y^2$ (this is easily seen to be interdefinable with $\bR^2$ with an isomorphism with its dual). I claim that there is no positive definite quadratic definable from this data.
Note that if $x>1$, then the automorphism of $V$ given by the matrix $P=\begin{pmatrix}x&\sqrt{x^2-1}\\\sqrt{x^2-1}&x\end{pmatrix}$ preserves the Lorentzian. We will show that if $A=\begin{pmatrix}a&b\\b&c\end{pmatrix}$ is a symmetric matrix such that $PAP^\top=A$ for each such $P$, then $a+c=b=0$, whence $A$ is not the matrix of a positive definite quadratic. This is enough, since any quadratic which is definable, finitarily or not, will necessarily be invariant under automorphisms.
Simple calculation (considering the upper left coefficient) shows that $PAP^\top=A$ implies that $2bx=-(c+a)\sqrt{x^2-1}$, which we have for all $x>1$. Since $\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2-1}}$ is not constant, it follows that $b=c+a=0$.
I suspect that in general, given a vector space $V$ over an infinite field with a quadratic $Q$, the only invariant quadratics in $(V,Q)$ are the scalar multiples of $Q$, but I don't quite see the general argument.

Thanks! I think this resolves the question in $R^2$, and I agree that it seems like it should generalize. I just wish I knew a more "powerful" way to prove things like this though that would just easily resolve this question and similar questions.
